# Lighning Web Components : Passing Javascript string var to HTML href tag

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am trying to bind static url with parameters from Javascript and its not working. Tried several variants

```
<lightning-tile label={option.label} href="https://www.google.com/search?q={option.label}" type="media">
```

html:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
            A list of tile components with dividers.
        </h2>

        <!-- Simple -->
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                    <template for:each={options} for:item='option'>
                        <ul class="slds-has-dividers_bottom-space" key={option.label}>
                            <li class="slds-item">
                                **<lightning-tile label={option.label} href="https://www.google.com/search?q={option.label}" type="media">**
                                    <lightning-avatar slot="media" fallback-icon-name="standard:file"></lightning-avatar>
                                    <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-dividers_right" key={option.label}>
                                        <li class="slds-item">{option.value}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </lightning-tile>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JavaScript :

```
export default class TileList extends LightningElement {

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
            { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
            { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
            { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
            { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
            { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' },
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`href="https://www.google.com/search?q={option.label}"` seems like you are trying to do expression evaluation in the markup. As of now LWC markup does not support [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC3gQAG).

You have to add that concatenated URL in your option's array object.

```
 get options() {
        let myArray  = [
            { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
            { label: 'German', value: 'de' },
            { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
            { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
            { label: 'Italian', value: 'it' },
            { label: 'Japanese', value: 'ja' },
        ];

        myArray.forEach(function(element){

            element.url='https://www.google.com/search?q='+ element.label;
        });

        return myArray;
    }
```

Markup:

```
<template for:each={options} for:item='option'>
                        <ul class="slds-has-dividers_bottom-space" key={option.label}>
                            <li class="slds-item">
                                <lightning-tile label={option.label} href= {option.url}  type="media">
                                    <lightning-avatar slot="media" fallback-icon-name="standard:file"></lightning-avatar>
                                    <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-dividers_right" key={option.label}>
                                        <li class="slds-item">{option.value}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </lightning-tile>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

</template>
```

Src : [Expression Functions within Lightning Web Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/expression-functions-within-lightning-web-components)