# Issue with for:each Index in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

In LWC am trying to iterate over a list and show the details from the list, this is working correctly , but as a header want to show the record number in a displayed order, below is desired outcome and simplified sample code.

Desired OutCome:

```
Employee Record 1:
A

Employee Record 2:
B

Employee Record 3:
C
```

JavaScript:

```
Var empNames = ["A" , "B" , "C"];
```

HTML:

```
<template for:each={empNames} for:item="employee" for:index="index">
Employee Record{index}
{employee}
</template>
```

Actual outcome

```
Employee Record 0:
A

Employee Record 1:
B

Employee Record 2:
C
```

I understand as i am using {index} which indicated the position of element in an array which starts from 0 my actual outcome also starts like Employee Record 0 instead of Employee Record 1, but is there a simple way without writing much logic on JS to handle this in html and to make my headers starts from 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 11):

LWC does not support [expression evaluation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/expression-functions-for-lightning-web-components/244464#244464) in the markup yet. I have raised an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC3gQAG) for it a few months back.

You have alter your JS to support complex javascript object with index of your choice.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

    export default class App extends LightningElement {

        @api empNames = [ { name: "A" , index : 1} ,{ name: "B" , index : 2} , { name: "C" , index :3} ];
    }
```

Markup:

```
<template>
      <ul>
        <template for:each={empNames} for:item="employee" for:index="index">
             <li key={employee.index}> Employee Record {employee.index}
                {employee.name} 
             </li>
        </template> 
    </ul>
</template>
```

[Playground Link.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pebUEqABf/1/edit)

Answer (score 8):

Its not `Var`. Its `var` (case sensitive).

This is not possible because using LWC iterators you will be able to get `item`, `index`, `firstItem`, and `lastItem`. You can use either `for:each` or `iterator:iteratorName`. And in HTML you cannot do any calculations. Also getters is not possible because its inside loop. So, you have to implement in javascript only.

Its actually simple in javascript:

```
    this.empNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
    this.empNames = this.empNames.map((name, index) => {
        return { name, sno: index + 1 };
    });
```

And in HTML:

```
<template for:each={empNames} for:item="employee" for:index="index">
    <div key={employee.sno}>
        Employee Record{employee.sno}
        {employee.name}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @rajasekhar, is this not solved?