# Can we have ternary operator in DIV tag -- LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Can we write  ternary operator in DIV tag on LWC as below.

```
<div class = if:true= {showleftDiv} ? slds-size_4-of-6 : slds-size_4-of-6 >
```

Comment: check :
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/expression-functions-for-lightning-web-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/expression-functions-for-lightning-web-components)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move all the expressions into js. This is done on purpose to make the code more testable as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/migrate_expressions)

**Example**

Html

```
<div class={divClass}></div>
```

JS

```
get divClass() {
   return this.showleftDiv ? 'slds-size_4-of-6' : 'slds-size_6-of-6';
}
```