# Pass param to JS from html for rendering during iteration?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I want to check if the metadata.datatype === 'Checkbox' although i am not able to pass the param from html to js in LWC.

Code:

```html
<template>
    <template for:each={caseMetadata.data} for:item="metaData" for:index="index">
        <div key={metaData.Id}>
        Type: {metaData.DataType}
        <div if:true={isCheckBox}>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Basic option" name="input1"></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
 import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
 import getCaseMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreateUpdateCTRL.fetchMetadata';
 
 export default class CreateCaseUpdateCmp extends LightningElement {
     @wire(getCaseMetadata) caseMetadata;
 
     get isCheckBox() {
         //Have to check if the metadata.DataType is Checkbox
         return true;
       }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression Functions for Lightning Web Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/expression-functions-for-lightning-web-components)

Comment: I tried doing the same mentioned in your link but doesn't work out for me. I applied console and it is saying undefined.

Comment: You might be doing something wrong as second option from that link should work for you.

Comment: I tried option 1 as I have to do lot of if condition going further. Option 1 doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just saying it doesn't work, doesn't give us any idea what could be wrong. You might want to create new question with snippets of code you built for option1 and stating what is not working (error or no result etc)

Comment: not new question, rather update this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in lwc. You need to compute the `isCheckbox` value in your wire adapter and then use this attribute in the html. Something like this.

```
caseMetadata;
@wire(getCaseMetadata)
process(result) {
 if (result.data) {
  const data = [];
  result.data.forEach(item=>{
   data.push({...item, isChecbox: your definition here});
  });
 }
}
```

then in your html you will simply get this attribute

```
<template for:each={caseMetadata.data} for:item="metaData" for:index="index">
        <div key={metaData.Id}>
        Type: {metaData.DataType}
        <div if:true={metaData.isCheckBox}>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Basic option" name="input1"></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

be aware that this is rather pseudocode than production ready js.